# Reassigning VSTS source code repos to a different VSTS account

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, tfvc

The situation is like this: there are two companies involved with a project.  *CompanyA* manages a VSTS account, under which there are several source code repositories, some TFVC, some Git.  The goal is to end up with the repos under a VSTS account belonging to *CompanyB*.

Is this possible somehow, without recreating the repositories and migrating their contents?  Migrating the repositories would be a solution, but I am not asking about how to perform migration, because I would like to avoid that.

I have found a doc which might be relevant, [but I don't quite understand](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/change-azure-active-directory-team-services-account).

Comment: can you explain which bits you don't; understand?

Comment: I am not familiar with some basic terms, such as 'tenant', 'AAD tenant', 'directory'  (the 'VSTS account' I understand).  Therefore I am not sure that this documentation talks about the same scenario, or something else.

Comment: Your VSTS account may be linked to Azure Active Directory to authenticate it's users (it may not be). If it is, the Azure Active Directory for your company is called a "tenant". It's also possible you're not linked to AAD and are using Microsoft Accounts, which would actually make the "full handover" scenario easier. But would still not enable a partial transfer without migration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are able to hand over the *whole* VSTS account, there is no way to hand over specific projects without migration (TFVC) or creating a mirror clone (Git).

Migrating with all work items, test history etc in place is even harder.

If you're able to migrate everything, then the process is as follows:

- Add a AAD account from company B as guest to the AAD of company A.
- Grant the user permissions on the VSTS account of Company A.
- Let the user logon once to the VSTS account of Company A.
- Assign Ownership of the account to the user from Company B.
- Associate the VSTS account to the Azure subscription and AAD of Company B.

That will complete the transfer process.

There are a few catch-22 situations you may encounter (especially in adding the user from Company B if neither company supports AAD guest account). And if that's the case you can probably submit a [support request to have Microsoft perform the handoff in the backend for you](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/support/#vsts-support).

Comment: I see!  I understand that 'Hand over the whole VSTS account' means that it would affect all projects within the account.  If there are some projects that are private to CompanyA, and should not be moved, that's not possible (those would have to migrated and deleted, maybe).

Comment: Correct. That;s the gist of it.